# attendance csv file upload django multiple employees

Tags: python, django, csv

#### views.py

```
def Add_Atten ( request ):
    data = {}
    attendance = Attendance.objects.all ( )
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render ( request , 'hr/attendance.html' , {'attendance': attendance} )
    # if not GET, then proceed
    # try:
    #     csv_file = request.FILES[ "csv_file" ]
    #     if not csv_file.name.endswith ( '.csv' ):
    #         messages.error ( request , 'File is not CSV type' )
    #         return render ( request , 'hr/attendance.html' , {'attendance': attendance} )
    #     # if file is too large, return
    #     if csv_file.multiple_chunks ( ):
    #         messages.error ( request , "Uploaded file is too big (%.2f MB)." % (csv_file.size / (1000 * 1000) ,) )
    #         return render ( request , 'hr/attendance.html' , {'attendance': attendance} )
    else:
        added_by = request.POST.get('added_by', '')
        month = request.POST.get('month', '')
        year = request.POST.get('year', '')
        att = request.FILES['csv_file']
        a1 = add_attendace(added_by=added_by, month=month, year=year,file=att)
        a1.save()
        csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file"]
        file_data = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")

        lines = file_data.split ( "\n" )
        # loop over the lines and save them in db. If error , store as string and then display
        for line in lines:
            fields = line.split(",")
            data_dict = {}
            data_dict["department"] = fields[1]
            data_dict["role"] = fields[2]
            data_dict["one"] = fields[3]
            data_dict["two"] = fields[4]
            data_dict["three"] = fields[5]
            data_dict["four"] = fields[6]
            data_dict["five"] = fields[7]
            data_dict["six"] = fields[8]
            data_dict["seven"] = fields[9]
            data_dict["eight"] = fields[10]
            data_dict["nine"] = fields[11]
            data_dict["ten"] = fields[12]
            data_dict["eleven"] = fields[13]
            data_dict["twelve"] = fields[14]
            data_dict["thirteen"] = fields[15]
            data_dict["fourteen"] = fields[16]
            data_dict["fifteen"] = fields[17]
            data_dict["sixteen"] = fields[18]
            data_dict["seventeen"] = fields[19]
            data_dict["eighteen"] = fields[20]
            data_dict["nineteen"] = fields[21]
            data_dict["twenty"] = fields[22]
            data_dict["twentyone"] = fields[23]
            data_dict["twentytwo"] = fields[24]
            data_dict["twentythree"] = fields[25]
            data_dict["twentyfour"] = fields[26]
            data_dict["twentyfive"] = fields[27]
            data_dict["twentysix"] = fields[28]
            data_dict["twentyseven"] = fields[29]
            data_dict["twentyeight"] = fields[30]
            data_dict["twentynine"] = fields[31]
            data_dict["thirty"] = fields[32]
            data_dict["thirtyone"] = fields[33]
            data_dict["total"] = fields[35]
            data_dict["leaves"] = fields[36]
            data_dict["month"] = fields[37]
            data_dict["employee_name"] = fields[34]
            return HttpResponse(data_dict['total'])

            form = Attendance_form(data_dict)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()

                # return render(request,'hr/index.html',{'attendance':attendance})
        return render(request,'hr/index.html',{'attendance':attendance})


The above code here is a function which takes csv file as an input and converts into python dictionary format and adds into the database. the code was working properly until i added month field into the model . after adding the month field i altered in the forms.py  models.py csv_file also i added the month detail.
```

Now if i add the csv file i am gettting a error

#### file.csv

```
1,it,manager,0.75,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,NULL,NULL,sunny,august
2,accounts,manager,1,0.5,0.75,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4.25,NULL,abdul,august
3,it,developer,1,0.75,0.5,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,0,1,NULL,NULL,mahesh,augustL
4,it,developer,1,0.75,0.5,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,0,1,NULL,NULL,firoz,august
5,it,developer,1,0.5,0.75,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,0,0.5,NULL,NULL,narayana,august
```

Here is the csv file which i have uploaded as i said first it took the data but now im getting this error.

output:

```
IndexError at /hrmsapp/Add_Attendance
list index out of range
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hrmsapp/Add_Attendance
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
Exception Location: /home/admin1/Desktop/nar-backup/dd/django-ubuntu/hrmsprojects/hrmsapp/views.py in Add_Atten, line 102
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Python Path:    
['/home/admin1/Desktop/nar-backup/dd/django-ubuntu/hrmsprojects',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/admin1/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 3 Aug 2018 11:00:59 +0000
```

This is the output file or error which i am getting once after i altered the code,.

Comment: Can you please point out which one is line 102?
Your exception says: 
Exception Location: /home/admin1/Desktop/nar-backup/dd/django-ubuntu/hrmsprojects/hrmsapp/views.py in Add_Atten, line 102

Comment: line 102 is nothing but this    102 -            data_dict["department"] = fields[1]